# Is it okay to link to a new proposal on Area51 inside an existing tag wiki description of another site?

Tags: discussion, tags, area-51, tag-wiki

On Stack Overflow just stumbled over the tag wiki entry for [`concrete5`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6655728/revisions) where a link to the ["*concrete5*" proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94596/concrete5) from Area51 was included to the wiki entry:

> [image: screenshot of concrete5 wiki entry; taken on 01.21.2016]

Now I wonder if this okay, because promoting a new proposal using an existing Stack Overflow tag looks a little bit strange to me?

Comment: It really comes off as weird to me, but considering that Pekka was behind one of the edits, I must be missing something.

Answer (score 4):

Tag wikis are somewhat free form to some extent, so in this ***specific*** case where there is literally a site being proposed about the tag itself, it seems okay to mention it.

But generally speaking, soliciting support for a proposal wherever you can find a place to type on these sites is ***not*** allowed. With so many proposals vying for attention, allowing folks to start soliciting support by commenting on questions and posting on meta gets out of control really fast. Except for the rarest, rarest exception, that content should be flagged and removed.

Comment: But IMHO promoting a new site using an existing tag of an other site, would usually lead to a duplicate proposal automatically, because this subject is on-topic already on the other site anyway?

Comment: @elegent You can't know that until see what has actually developed. Many of our content-management sites would make a terrible fit on Stack Overflow. I don't know if this will end up being a dupe or not; I am only advocating for the process to flesh that out.

Comment: I see :) But I don't really understand why there is no CMS.SE site (proposal), because this is what SE wants (?): (from the [Area51 Help Page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) )"*In general, if a site makes sense as part of a bigger site, **it's better to have one big site** than a bunch of little niche sites.*"

Comment: @elegent Ask the people who ***didn't* support it** the many many times it was proposed and fizzled out for lack of support.

Comment: Perhaps because it's too late now, since some of the big CMS communities -- such as WordPress or Joomla-- already have there own .SE sites...

Comment: @elegent Because those were the ones that actually made it. I'm not sure you're seeing "the community creates these" sites aspect of this.